For what values of $a$ is the set $A$ linearly dependent?
Recently I tried to solve this problem:
set $A =
\begin{align*}
    \{1 + ax, 
    x + ax^2,
    x^2 + ax^3, 
    x^3 + ax^4, 
    x^4 + ax^5, 
    x^5 + ax^6, 
    a + \bar{a}x^6\}
\end{align*}$
I tried to solve the determinant of this set and it should be equal to zero (since we want the set to be dependent) but I come to this and can't understand how to solve it: $\det A=0 \implies a^7=\bar{a}$
Any help will be appreciated.

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

A assume by "a conjugate," you mean the complex conjugate, $\overline a$.

exactly, sorry for the bad format previously.

Weird, mathjax on my computer gives \overline{a} x with the overline above both $a$ and $x.$

Let’s solve $a^7 = \overline{a}.$
Since two complex numbers are equal, their modules are equal too. So we have
$|a|^7=|a^7|=|\overline{a}|=|a|$, hence $|a|=1$. So $a=\cos \alpha + i \sin \alpha$, then $\overline{a}=\cos (-\alpha) + i \sin (-\alpha)$ and $a^7=\cos 7\alpha + i \sin 7\alpha$. Then you have $7\alpha + 2\pi k= -\alpha, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
Then $\alpha = \frac{\pi}{4}k$.
Which gives you $a = \pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \pm i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} $.
